# Deriving d'Alemberts formula from Riemann function

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Im currently trying to derive d'Alemberts formula for wave equation in dimension $n=1$ from the Riemann function, and don't end up where I want.

I want to show that $$u(t,x)=\frac{1}{2}\big( g(x-ct)+g(x+ct)\big) + \frac{1}{2c} \int_{x-ct}^{x+ct} h(y) \ dy$$ from the general solution that is $$u(t,x)=h(x) * R_t(x)+ \partial_t \big(g(x) * R_t(x) \big)$$ with $g(x)=u(0,x)$ and $h(x) = \partial_t u(0,x)$ and $$R_t(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{2c}, |x|< ct \\
0, |x|>ct \end{cases}$$

Using definitions above I get stuck at

$$u(t,x)=\frac{1}{2c} \int_{x-ct}^{x+ct}h(y) \ dy+\partial_t \Big(\frac{1}{2c} \int_{x-ct}^{x+ct} g(y) \ dy \Big)$$

I am satisfied with the first term, but the second term have a time derivative, and $1/c$ I want to get rid of.

Would anyone mind help me explain?

Comment: Use [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) to simplify the second term.